# KeyCloak Node.js adapter gives KeyCloak page not found for public clients and access denies for bearer-only clients

Tags: node.js, keycloak

When I set up a public client in Keycloak, setting all required fields for my local sandbox

- Access Type: public
- Valid Redirect URIs: http://localhost:3000/*
- Web Origins: *

I save the Keycloak OIDC JSON from the installation tab to a local `keycloak.json` file, add my Node.js app and hit http://localhost:3000/protected, I get the following page in my browser:

[image]

**The url contains an extra `/` after the `auth-server-url`. Here is my `keycloak.json`:

```js
{
  "realm": "keycloak-node-monolith",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "keycloak-node-monolith-public",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

The problem is less obvious in case of bearer-only clients, because there is no authentication redirect and you don't see the URL.

**In case of bearer-only clients all you see is Access Denied even if you are sending the right bearer tokens to your server.**

The root cause of the issue is the same in both cases:
**Keycloak-connect adds an extra `/` after the `auth-server-url`, so you have to remove the `/` in your `keycloak.json`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the issue is that `keycloak-connect` will add an extra `/` after the `auth-server-url` in `keycloak.json`.

This means that you cannot use your Keycloak OIDC JSON in the exact form you copied it from your Clients form from Keycloak, you have to remove the trailing `/` from `auth-server-url`. This works for me:

```js
{
  "realm": "keycloak-node-monolith",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "keycloak-node-monolith-public",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

This is annoying if you are building a bearer-only use-case, because you don't see the URLs. It took me while to work it out. I found the solution after I built a public client and saw what's going on.

**The issue is logged in the Keycloak issue tracker with Critical priority and is expected to be released with 9.0.0. You can see the issue here https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-12428.**